# VHDL - XULA, finite state machine

Tags: warnings, vhdl, state-machine

I have a XULA2 and am following some tutorials and have successfully made an LED flash on and off.  Now I am trying to move ahead and implement a state machine (to do basically the same thing - for now) and am getting some warnings and eventually the build fails to generate an output file.

The errors are of the form (some similar warnings removed for clarity):

```
WARNING:Xst:1710 - FF/Latch <wait_time_msec_7> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <BigDisplayMain>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
WARNING:Xst:1710 - FF/Latch <wait_time_msec_8> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <BigDisplayMain>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process...
WARNING:Xst:1710 - FF/Latch <wait_time_msec_15> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <BigDisplayMain>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
WARNING:Xst:1293 - FF/Latch <fsm_display_1> has a constant value of 0 in block <BigDisplayMain>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
WARNING:Xst:1293 - FF/Latch <fsm_display_0> has a constant value of 0 in block <BigDisplayMain>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
WARNING:Xst:1293 - FF/Latch <cntr_time_delay_19> has a constant value of 0 in block <BigDisplayMain>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process....
WARNING:Xst:1293 - FF/Latch <cntr_time_delay_0> has a constant value of 0 in block <BigDisplayMain>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
WARNING:Xst:1710 - FF/Latch <wait_time_msec_9> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <BigDisplayMain>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process....
WARNING:Xst:1710 - FF/Latch <wait_time_msec_0> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <BigDisplayMain>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
WARNING:Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <blinker_o> (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block <BigDisplayMain>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
WARNING:Xst:1898 - Due to constant pushing, FF/Latch <return_state_0> is unconnected in block <BigDisplayMain>.
```

.

I have a rough understanding why unused values might generate some trimmed FFs so those don't bother me...much (I do have a question about this, but later after my main problem is solved)

A quick explanation of my code is it's a state machine with 4 states - `INIT, START0, START1 and DELAY`.  What I want to happen is for the device to start in `INIT` then proceed to go in a loop from `START0` to `DELAY` to `START1` to `DELAY` and back to `START0` etc., toggling the signal to the LED along the way (via  `blinker_o`).  Certainly this is a more complicated way than necessary to attempt to blink an LED but it's an academic exercise as I learn how to do a more sophisticated task, centered around using a `DELAY` state.

Anyway the compiler concluded `blinker_o` was hardwired to '0' (at `WARNING:Xst:1895`). Of course this is NOT what I'd like!

I've stripped down my code as much as I can to illustrate the problem (other than to leave in the "reset" signal )

Your time and assistance is appreciated!

Here's the code:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

library UNISIM;
use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity BigDisplayMain is
    port (         clk_i : in   std_logic;
               blinker_o : out  std_logic
         );
end BigDisplayMain;

architecture Behavioral of BigDisplayMain is

signal       clk_1MHZ  : std_logic;
signal           reset : std_logic := '0';
signal  wait_time_msec : natural range 0 to 1_000_000;
signal cntr_time_delay : natural range 0 to 1_000_000;

type fsmA is (
FSM_INIT, FSM_STATE_DISPLAY_START0, FSM_STATE_DISPLAY_START1, FSM_STATE_DELAY
);
signal fsm_display  : fsmA;
signal return_state : fsmA;

begin
   -- DCM_CLKGEN: Frequency Aligned Digital Clock Manager
   --             Spartan-6
   -- Xilinx HDL Language Template, version 14.7

   reset <= '0';

   DCM_CLKGEN_inst : DCM_SP
   generic map (
      CLKFX_DIVIDE => 24,        -- Divide value - D - (1-256)
      CLKFX_MULTIPLY => 2       -- Multiply value - M - (2-256)
   )
   port map (
      CLKFX => clk_1MHZ,         -- 1-bit output: Generated clock output
      CLKIN => clk_i,         -- 1-bit input: Input clock
      RST => '0'              -- 1-bit input: Reset input pin
   );

   -- End of DCM_CLKGEN_inst instantiation

process(clk_1MHz, reset) is
begin
    if reset = '1' then
        cntr_time_delay <= 0;
        fsm_display <= FSM_INIT;
        wait_time_msec <= 0;
        blinker_o <= '0';

    elsif rising_edge(clk_1MHZ) then
        case fsm_display is
            when FSM_INIT => 
                cntr_time_delay <= 0;
                wait_time_msec <= 0;
                return_state <= FSM_STATE_DISPLAY_START0;

            when FSM_STATE_DISPLAY_INIT_START0 =>
                blinker_o <= '0';
                wait_time_msec <= 1_000_000;
                return_state <= FSM_STATE_DISPLAY_START1;
                fsm_display <= FSM_STATE_DELAY;

            when FSM_STATE_DISPLAY_INIT_START1 =>
                blinker_o <= '1';
                wait_time_msec <= 999_999;
                return_state <= FSM_STATE_DISPLAY_START0;
                fsm_display <= FSM_STATE_DELAY;

            when FSM_STATE_DELAY =>
                if cntr_time_delay >= wait_time_msec then
                    fsm_display <= return_state;
                    cntr_time_delay <= 0;
                else
                    cntr_time_delay <= cntr_time_delay + 1;
                    fsm_display <= FSM_STATE_DELAY;
                end if;

            when others =>
                null;
        end case;

    end if;     
end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: You haven't posted any errors. Warnings can (usually) be ignored : in this case, they are all optimisations that reduce the volume of logic produced. Assuming the design did what you want in simulation, they are normal and don't indicate anything wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You don't appear to have simulated this design.

I analyzed it and the enumeration names in the choices:

```
            when FSM_STATE_DISPLAY_INIT_START0 =>
```

and

```
            when FSM_STATE_DISPLAY_INIT_START1 =>
```

are not in the declaration for type fsma:

```
type fsmA is (
FSM_INIT, FSM_STATE_DISPLAY_START0, FSM_STATE_DISPLAY_START1,  FSM_STATE_DELAY
);
```

I corrected the choices to match the declared fsma states and commented out the instantiated component, assigning clk_i to clk_1MHZ and wrote a small test bench:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
-- use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
-- use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
--
-- library UNISIM;
-- use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity BigDisplayMain is
    port ( 
        clk_i:      in   std_logic;
        -- reset:      in   std_logic;
        blinker_o:  out  std_logic
         );
end BigDisplayMain;

architecture Behavioral of BigDisplayMain is

signal       clk_1MHZ:   std_logic;
signal           reset:  std_logic := '0'; -- COMMENT out if driven by testbench
signal  wait_time_msec:  natural range 0 to 1_000_000;
signal cntr_time_delay:  natural range 0 to 1_000_000;

type fsmA is (
    FSM_INIT, 
    FSM_STATE_DISPLAY_START0, 
    FSM_STATE_DISPLAY_START1, 
    FSM_STATE_DELAY
);
signal fsm_display:   fsmA;
signal return_state:  fsmA;

begin
   -- DCM_CLKGEN: Frequency Aligned Digital Clock Manager
   --             Spartan-6
   -- Xilinx HDL Language Template, version 14.7

   reset <= '0';  -- COMMENT out if driven by test bench

   -- DCM_CLKGEN_inst:  DCM_SP
   -- generic map (
   --    CLKFX_DIVIDE => 24,        -- Divide value - D - (1-256)
   --    CLKFX_MULTIPLY => 2       -- Multiply value - M - (2-256)
   -- )
   -- port map (
   --    CLKFX => clk_1MHZ,         -- 1-bit output: Generated clock output
   --    CLKIN => clk_i,         -- 1-bit input: Input clock
   --    RST => '0'              -- 1-bit input: Reset input pin
   -- );

   -- End of DCM_CLKGEN_inst instantiation

   clk_1MHZ <= clk_i;  -- ADDED debug

    process(clk_1MHz, reset) is
    begin
        if reset = '1' then
            cntr_time_delay <= 0;
            fsm_display <= FSM_INIT;
            wait_time_msec <= 0;
            blinker_o <= '0';

        elsif rising_edge(clk_1MHZ) then
            case fsm_display is
                when FSM_INIT => 
                    cntr_time_delay <= 0;
                    wait_time_msec <= 0;
                    return_state <= FSM_STATE_DISPLAY_START0;
                    fsm_display <= FSM_STATE_DELAY; -- ADDED branch

                when FSM_STATE_DISPLAY_START0 => -- REMOVED _INIT
                    blinker_o <= '0';
                    wait_time_msec <= 10; -- 1_000_000; -- FOR SIMULATION
                    return_state <= FSM_STATE_DISPLAY_START1;
                    fsm_display <= FSM_STATE_DELAY;

                when FSM_STATE_DISPLAY_START1 => -- REMOVED _INIT
                    blinker_o <= '1';
                    wait_time_msec <= 9; -- 999_999;  -- FOR SIMULTION
                    return_state <= FSM_STATE_DISPLAY_START0;
                    fsm_display <= FSM_STATE_DELAY;

                when FSM_STATE_DELAY =>
                    if cntr_time_delay >= wait_time_msec then
                        fsm_display <= return_state;
                        cntr_time_delay <= 0;
                    else
                        cntr_time_delay <= cntr_time_delay + 1;
                        fsm_display <= FSM_STATE_DELAY;
                    end if;
                when others =>
                    null;
            end case;
        end if;     
    end process;
end architecture Behavioral;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity bigdisplaymain_tb is
end entity;

architecture foo of bigdisplaymain_tb is
    signal clk_i:       std_logic := '0';
    -- signal reset:       std_logic := '0';
    signal blinker_o:   std_logic;
begin
CLOCK:
    process
    begin
        wait for 500 ns;
        clk_i <= not clk_i;
        if now > 120 us then
            wait;
        end if;
    end process;

    DUT:
        entity work.bigdisplaymain 
            port map (
                clk_i => clk_i,
                -- reset => reset,
                blinker_o => blinker_o
            );

-- STIMULI:
--     process
--     begin
--         wait for 1 us;
--         reset <= '1';
--         wait for 1 us;
--         reset <= '0';
--         wait;
--     end process;

end architecture;
```

Most importantly I added the branch from state FSM_INIT to STATE_DELAY:

```
                when FSM_INIT => 
                    cntr_time_delay <= 0;
                    wait_time_msec <= 0;
                    return_state <= FSM_STATE_DISPLAY_START0;
                    fsm_display <= FSM_STATE_DELAY; -- ADDED branch
```

Without this branch it sort of sat there.

With the shorted time delays to 9 and 10 this gives:

[image: bigdisplaymain_tb.png]

It's likely the missing branch in state FSM_INIT is responsible for all your synthesis warnings and flip flops being eaten. None of them were being used and blinker_o would be the reset value (assuming reset were actually used).